# Why do shape files store geo coordinates with Longitude first?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, geo

Just about everywhere else references geo coordinates as x=latitude,y=longitude.   This is generally thought to be for historical reasons of which measurement had the higher accuracy.

Does anyone know why almost all GIS geo spatial shape file formats stores their coordinates as x=longitude, y=latitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's related to the right-hand-rule:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule.

Comment: Makes sense... longitude goes horizontal along x in Cartesian graph and latitude is the vertical.  I guess it just sucks we traditionally use Lat, Long everywhere humans have to consume it.